# Get Currently Opened Word Document from Process

Tags: c#, winapi, com, office-interop, com-interop

The goal is to get the full path to the document opened in an instance of Microsoft Word that I have a process reference for.

**Pseudocode Example:**

```
Process myWordProcess = something; // This is my process reference
DocumentInformation docInfo = SomeNamespace.GetDocumentInformation(myWordProcess);
string documentPath = docInfo.FullName; // "C:\User\Foo\Documents\Test.docx"
```

The starting point is a `Process` object which is executed by `WINWORD.exe`.

I am not looking for a way that includes parsing `process.MainWindowTitle`, but rather a more, let's say, "proper" solution.

Having done a fair bit of initial research, I believe what's required is the Windows Accessibility API.

[Pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/oleacc.accessibleobjectfromwindow) mentiones the `AccessibleObjectFromWindow` signature.  That being said, the resulting `accessible` object does not provide me with much more information than the `process` already does.

Here's what I tried from Pinvoke:

```
internal enum OBJID : uint
{
    WINDOW = 0x00000000,
    SYSMENU = 0xFFFFFFFF,
    TITLEBAR = 0xFFFFFFFE,
    MENU = 0xFFFFFFFD,
    CLIENT = 0xFFFFFFFC,
    VSCROLL = 0xFFFFFFFB,
    HSCROLL = 0xFFFFFFFA,
    SIZEGRIP = 0xFFFFFFF9,
    CARET = 0xFFFFFFF8,
    CURSOR = 0xFFFFFFF7,
    ALERT = 0xFFFFFFF6,
    SOUND = 0xFFFFFFF5,
}

public class DocumentLocator
{
    [DllImport("oleacc.dll")]
    internal static extern int AccessibleObjectFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, uint id, ref Guid iid, [In] [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] ref object ppvObject);

    public static void GetWordInfo(Process process)
    {
        var mainWindowHandle = process.MainWindowHandle;
        var guid = new Guid("{618736E0-3C3D-11CF-810C-00AA00389B71}");

        object obj = null;
        var retVal = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(mainWindowHandle, (uint)OBJID.WINDOW, ref guid, ref obj);
        var accessible = (IAccessible) obj; // Not much information is contained in this object
    }
}
```

Perhaps the solution is to somehow get a `Document` interface (Office COM Interop, [see here for the interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.document(v=office.14).aspx)) from the process or window handle?  Or, perhaps, first getting a [Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.window(v=office.14).aspx) and then the `Document`?

Then, equipped with that information from Office Interop, one could read the `Path` property.

I am open to any solutions for this.

If you know how to perform this regarding Excel or PowerPoint - then that would be fine, too, as I assume the same process can be applied for Word (after changing a couple of interfaces and GUIDs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borrowing some code from [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316126/how-to-use-visual-c-to-automate-a-running-instance-of-an-office-progra), the key method for which is `GetActiveObject`:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object wordAsObject;
            Word.Application word;

            try
            {
                wordAsObject = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
                //If there is a running Word instance, it gets saved into the word variable
                word = (Word.Application)wordAsObject;

                Console.WriteLine("{0}", word.ActiveDocument.FullName);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (COMException)
            {
                //If there is no running instance, it creates a new one
                //Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
                //wordAsObject = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You still have a reference to the running *process* if you need it.

It is a simple matter to iterate the `Documents` collection if needed.

```
foreach (Word.Document doc in word.Documents)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", doc.FullName);
}
```

Comment: Wow - this was easier than I thought - thanks a lot! By casting the object to dynamic, I can even get around referencing the Interop assemblies (with a bit of try/catch). This works for all Office apps, and I also managed to get hold of the current document and solution of a Visual Studio instance (`VisualStudio.DTE.15.0`). Just out of interest, is there a "list" of such ActiveObjects? It could help find open documents for a host of other applications (e.g. Windows photo app, the current Explorer path, etc.).

Comment: @JDR I don't know of such a list, but if you have a look in the Registry at `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application`, etc., these keys provide a good clue as to the text to use as the class-name.

Comment: Thanks! That registry location is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of all word opened document using following code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordObj;
WordObj = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
for (int i = 0; i < WordObj.Windows.Count; i++)
{
    object idx = i + 1;
    Window WinObj = WordObj.Windows.get_Item(ref idx);
    doc_list.Add(WinObj.Document.FullName);
}
```

Use following code to get active document full path

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordObj;
    WordObj =
 (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
    var word = (Word.Application)WordObj;
    string docPath=word.ActiveDocument.FullName;
```