# Comm object for Microsoft Word is not populated when Visual Studio is started with Admin Privileges

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, visual-studio-2019

What I Want to achieve is to get file opened in Microsoft Word using C#. I have tried the following code and its working fine. But when i start Visual Studio 2019 with administrator privileges and try the same code, it doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        #region OLE32 Methods
        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        static extern int GetRunningObjectTable(int reserved, out IRunningObjectTable prot);
        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        static extern int CreateBindCtx(uint reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);
        #endregion

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"File Name: {GetFileName()}");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error:{ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        public static string GetFileName()
        {
            IRunningObjectTable runningObjectTable;
            GetRunningObjectTable(0, out runningObjectTable);

            dynamic objValue = GetRunningInstances("Word.Application", runningObjectTable);

            if (objValue == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Word Application reference not found");
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Word Application reference found");
            }

            dynamic propValue = objValue.ActiveWindow;
            if (propValue == null) return string.Empty;

            propValue = objValue.ActiveDocument;
            if (propValue == null) return string.Empty;

            string fileName = propValue.FullName ?? string.Empty;
            return fileName;
        }

        static object GetRunningInstances(string progId, IRunningObjectTable Rot)
        {
            string clsId = null;

            Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progId);
            if (type != null)
                clsId = type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper();

            if (Rot == null)
                return null;

            // get enumerator for ROT entries
            IEnumMoniker monikerEnumerator = null;
            Rot.EnumRunning(out monikerEnumerator);

            if (monikerEnumerator == null)
                return null;

            monikerEnumerator.Reset();
            object instance = null;
            IntPtr pNumFetched = new IntPtr();
            IMoniker[] monikers = new IMoniker[1];

            // go through all entries and identifies app instances
            while (monikerEnumerator.Next(1, monikers, pNumFetched) == 0)
            {
                IBindCtx bindCtx;
                CreateBindCtx(0, out bindCtx);
                if (bindCtx == null)
                    continue;
                string displayName;
                monikers[0].GetDisplayName(bindCtx, null, out displayName);

                if (displayName.ToUpper().IndexOf(clsId) > 0)
                {
                    object ComObject;
                    Rot.GetObject(monikers[0], out ComObject);

                    if (ComObject == null)
                        continue;

                    instance = ComObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Environment I am using is

Visual Studio: **2019 v16.8.2**

Target Framework:**net5.0-windows**

Project Type: **Console**

**Steps to reproduce**

- Create a Console App Project and paste the above code in program.cs
- open any file in Microsoft Word and run the app, it will display the path of the file opened in MS Word
- Close Visual Studio, Open again with Administrative privileges and run the same project again, code will be unable to get path of the opened file.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I reproduced your problem. It is related to the GetRunningObjectTable method.

When we start the visual studio as the admin privileges, we only can see the processes that belongs to the admin. Of course, it also applies to standard users.

Therefore, when you use admin privileges for vs and standard privileges for ms-word, the parameter `runningObjectTable` will return null.

If you want to know more the details about the reason, you can refer to [Understanding the Running Object Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835617/understanding-the-running-object-table).

Finally, if you want to get the correct result when you start vs with admin privileges, you also need start the word file with admin privileges. According to my test, it can get the correct result.

Comment: Thanks for the useful reply. But the issue is that when I will ship this code. It will be the user who will start the word with admin privileges or not. What I can do is just to set my app to be run as Admin. I need solution for this problem.

Comment: According to "Principle of least privilege" when we run Visual studio with Admin privileges , It should see all processes from all users but here is the reverse case, i.e with admin privileges we don't see a process with normal user privileges. Even when I start both word and visual studio with admin privileges , I am unable to get the file name.

Comment: Sorry for the last statement of above comment. When i run both code and word with admin rights or regular user rights, it works. But I have to run my code with admin priviliges in any case. what can I do to get objects from all users using GetRunningObjectTable ?

Comment: @RashadMaqsood, have you considered another way by referring to the link [Get Currently Opened Word Document from Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321167/get-currently-opened-word-document-from-process)?